# How to format LocalDateTime with time zone offset

Tags: java, java-8

I tried to do it like this:

```
    ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(3);
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("dateTimeWithoutOffset: " + fmt.format(dateTime));

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, zoneOffset);
    System.out.println("dateWithOffset: " + fmt.format(zonedDateTime));
```

But I get the same output:

```
dateTimeWithoutOffset: 18:11:06
dateTimeWithOffset: 18:11:06
```

I want to see something like this:

```
dateTimeWithoutOffset: 18:11:06
dateTimeWithOffset: 21:11:06
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you can't add the offset, but you can display it. 
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE

Comment: @J.Mengelle I want to print formatted datetime with added timezone offset as it will be displayed in UI. This sample works, but I can't understand why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25885786/4853702

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to work with a zone offset, an `OffsetDateTime` would make more sense than a `ZonedDateTime`.

And to apply the offset to your local time, one way is to say that the time is in UTC and you want the local time in a different time zone. So it could look like:

```
OffsetDateTime timeUtc = dateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC); //18:11:06 UTC
OffsetDateTime offsetTime = timeUtc.withOffsetSameInstant(zoneOffset); //21:11:06 +03:00
System.out.println("dateWithOffset: " + fmt.format(offsetTime)); //21:11:06
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I was trying to do the opposite, and hunting around and came across this question, I used this to convert the date on the server (UTC) to -7 hours Phoenix, AZ USA time

Note:  the server was UTC

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
String myDate = date.format(dtf);
```

Hope it helps anyone else in a similar scenario!