# Convert UTC time to Europe/London timezone in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, localdatetime

I've current datetime in UTC but I need date time of timezone (Europe/London). I tried but everytime time is not adding instead of this offset is appending in current date time.

My code -

```
LocalDateTime utcTime = LocalDate.now().atTime(0,1);
System.out.println("utc time " + utcTime);
ZoneId europeLondonTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
ZoneOffset offset = europeLondonTimeZone.getRules().getOffset(utcTime);
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = utcTime.atOffset(offset);
System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
```

It will print:

```
"2021-06-18T00:01+01:00"
```

but I want

```
"2021-06-17T23:01"
```

as +01:00 is ahead in daylight saving time.

Thanks

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.now(europeLondonTimeZone)`.

Comment: maybe this thread will help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38227586/9183199

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the current time in Great Britain, there is no need to convert from UTC. You can have that time directly.

```
    ZoneId europeLondonTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(europeLondonTimeZone);
    System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
```

Output when I ran the code just now:

> ```
> 2021-06-18T19:18:39.599+01:00
> ```

If you do need to have the UTC time first, avoid using `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` for that. The *local* in some java.time class names means *without time zone or UTC offset*. Prefer `OffsetDateTime`, which itself keeps track of its offset, as the name says. So when it’s in UTC, it “knows” this fact itself.

```
    // Sample UTC time
    OffsetDateTime utcTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println("UTC time: " + utcTime);

    ZoneId europeLondonTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = utcTime.atZoneSameInstant(europeLondonTimeZone)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println("UK time:  " + offsetDateTime);
```

> ```
> UTC time: 2021-06-18T18:18:39.669Z
> UK time:  2021-06-18T19:18:39.669+01:00
> ```

The `atZoneSameInstant` method converts from whatever offset the `OffsetDateTime` was in (in this case UTC) to the time zone passed as argument, thus typically altering the clock time (sometimes even the date).

### What went wrong in your code?

A `LocalDate` contains a date without time of day only, so `LocalDate.now()` only gives you which day it is in the default time zone of your JVM (so not even which day it is in UTC), not the time of day. `.atTime(0,1)` converts that day to a `LocalDateTime` representing the time of 0 hours 1 minute, that is, 00:01, on that day, still without any time zone.

Also a `ZonedDateTime` not only knows its time zone but can also handle its time zone rules. So there is no reason for you to deal with the offset at a particular time yourself.

Finally `LocalDateTime.atOffset()` converts to an `OffsetDateTime` but neither changes the date nor the time of day. Since the `LocalDateTime` did not have any time zone, the method cannot be used for converting between time zones.