# need to subtract europe/london offset from current UTC time if DST is on

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, timezone-offset

I need to subtract timezone offset from current UTC time
example -> In below code,
In `dateTime` variable Date is today and time I've set 00:01, and than I got the offset of "Europe/London".

If there is no offset than in offset "Z" will come but if there is some
offset, than in case of "Europe/London" -> "+01:00"(in DST) will come. So, as per the requirement if offset will come I've to subtract that offset instead of adding it. but if there is no offset, than no need to do anything

My current Implementation for code -

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.now().atTime(0, 1);
ZoneId europeLondonTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
ZoneOffset offset = europeLondonTimeZone.getRules().getOffset(dateTime);
if (!offset.toString().equals("Z")){
   dateTime = dateTime.minusHours(1);
}
```

but i think it is not a generic one. If there is better approach, please comment down below.

Note - Here I'm subtracting offset from UTC instead of adding it.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to calculate?

Comment: Are you asking because we didn’t help you well enough with [your previous quetsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031365/convert-utc-time-to-europe-london-timezone-in-java)? Feel free to clarify that question and/or what you are still missing from it. We are here to help.

Comment: When running your code just now (2021-06-21T15:13:38.854343+01:00[Europe/London]), I get `2021-06-20T23:01`. I this the desired result?

Comment: yes, this is the result I want, but I think the way I implemented is not correct, If you think this is the correct approach, than I'll go this implementation. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) 
)
.atTime( 0 , 1 )
.atZone( 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) 
)
.toOffsetDateTime()
.withOffsetSameInstant( 
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)
```

## Details

Your Question is overwrought and confusing. But I am guessing that you want to take the current date at one minute past midnight as seen in a time zone, and adjust to UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Your code neglects to specify the time zone when getting the current date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. So time zone is crucial. If omitted, your JVM’s current default time zone is applied.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Apply the time-of-day to produce a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = today.atTime( 0 , 1 ) ;
```

Apply the time zone to determine a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Be aware that `ZonedDateTime` adjusts the time of day if yours is not valid on that date in that zone such as during a Daylight Saving Time (DST) cut-over.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

You want to adjust to UTC. No need to manage the offset calculations yourself. Let *java.time* do the work.

You could extract an `Instant`. This class represents a moment as seen in UTC, always UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

But `Instant` is the basic-building block class in *java.time*. If you need more flexibility such as formatting when generating text, use `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Comment: My suggestion was just slightly different, `ZonedDateTime.now(europeLondonTimeZone).with(localLondonTime)` where `localLondonTime` would be equal to 00:01. I don’t think it’s worth posting it now when you’ve answered the question so well.